# Python - making copies of a file

Tags: python, file, copy

I have a file that I want copied into a directory multiple times. It could be 100, it could be 1000. That's a variable.

I came up with this:

```
import shutil

count = 0
while (count < 100):
    shutil.copy2('/Users/bubble/Desktop/script.py', '/Users/bubble/Desktop/pics')
    count = count + 1
```

It puts 1 copy of the file in the directory, but only 1 file. My guess is that it doesn't automatically add a 2,3,4,5 etc onto the end of the file as it would if you were copying and pasting.

Any ideas how to do this?

Regards.

Comment: You do not change the file name so it is overridding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
import shutil

for i in range(100):
    shutil.copy2('/Users/bubble/Desktop/script.py', '/Users/bubble/Desktop/pics/script{}.py'.format(i))
```

To make it even more useful, one can add the format specifier `{:03d}` (3 digit numbers, i.e. 001, 002 etc.)
or `{:04d}` (4 digit numbers, i.e. 0001, 0002 etc.) according to their needs as suggested by [@Roland Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219295/roland-smith).

Comment: You might want to use the format specifier `{:03d}`. That way the files would be listed in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks Roland. I'll test that out now.